PS: Convert a IP address range to subnet mask
I have a range of IP addresses, which I need to convert into a subnet format to add to IIS for blocking / allowing them.
Can someone help me with a power shell function to convert an IP address range to the subnet mask format?
Something which this tool does: https://subnetonline.com/pages/subnet-calculators/subnetmask-calculator.php
Thanks,
Tushar

Does this answer your question? PowerShell: Convert IP Address to Subnet
